# How to use transaction and stored procedure at the same time?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064

Create a stored procedure that returns the total number of copies of a book our library owns, given a title A.
First,find the standard number(S) of A. 
Then, go through the ITEM table to find tuples where standard Number= S. 
Then, add the number of copies together to find the total number of copies the whole library system owns. Could please teach me how to fix these code?

```
use library;

select * from item;
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS FindNumberOfCopies;

CREATE PROCEDURE FindNumberOfCopies ( IN itemTitle varchar(150))
BEGIN
SELECT copies FROM item WHERE title = itemTitle;
ROLLBACK;
END;
START TRANSACTION;
    UPDATE item SET copies = newCopies where title = itemTitle;
COMMIT;
END
$$
```

Comment: I do not know what I miss, but it does not work.

Comment: first, there is no reason for the transaction

Comment: first, I got syntax error first.

Comment: But the store procedure that is correct, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS FindNumberOfCopies;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE FindNumberOfCopies
( 
 IN itemTitle varchar(150)
)
BEGIN
    SELECT copies FROM item WHERE title = itemTitle;

    UPDATE item SET copies = newCopies where title = itemTitle;
END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

There is no point in your `select`. There is no point in your transaction. You did a rollback of a transaction that did not even occur.

Each sql call regardless is a transaction. You are wrapping a trans with a trans. Along the way of this edit I somehow removed the 1064

Comment: Since my table has the same title name of books, so I hope to update and clear all duplicate data then store in the table.

Comment: what in the world are doing with the select copies. It is like an abandoned idea

Comment: I may be wrong too, but the orig delimiter line. That was TOO early

Comment: Yes, I want to delete some datas.

Comment: you don't want to delete some datas. You are performing an update stmt. When does that ever delete some datas b-y?

Comment: It does not delete data. I guess I find the answer already. Thank you so much Drew.